# remove a key from the JSON response

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I am using `Jersey` framework and trying to return `{"status":201}` as a response but I am getting `{"status":201,"route":0}` at the momenat. I need the route and direction in the  `SDBeanPost` class in another response but not in all response. Therefore, I was able to remove the direction from the response by addling this line  `bean.direction = null;` but I do not know how can I remove the route from the response without deleting `route` from the `SDBeanPost`?

**Receiver class**

```
package org.busTracker.trackingService;

/*
 * Inside this class, the request from the Android application - PostData class is received.
 *  Consequently, a response is sent back.
 */

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/data")
public class Receiver {
    static String flagD;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response proccessData(Data data) {

        Database db = new Database();

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        double latD = data.getLatitude();
        double longD = data.getLongitude();
        String timeD = data.getTime();
        int speedD = data.getSpeed();
        String directionD = data.getDirection();
        flagD = data.getFlag();

        // Jackson class to wrapper the data as JSON string.
        SDBeanPost bean = new SDBeanPost();
        bean.direction = null;      
        bean.status = 201;

        return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build();

    }

}
```

**SDBeanPost**

```
package org.busTracker.trackingService;

/*
 * Class to wrap the response for the Receiver class. 
 */

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

//To return status without route null.
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SDBeanPost {

    public int status;
    public int route;
    public String direction;

    public SDBeanPost() {
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver();

        direction = "";
        status = 230;

    }

    public String toJson() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you return an instance of SDBeanPost, which has a status, a route, and a direction, since you actually want to return only a status? Use a different class, which has the fields you want, and only those fields. Also, don't serialize to JSON yourself. Jersey does that for you. Returning a status in the body is also dubious, BTW. An HTTP response already has a status. So, unless the status in the body is a completely different kind of status, it shouldn't be in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

route is a primitive `int` in your class. So it's instance will have default value 0 for it when you don't explicitly set it and hence while serializing to json, it's coming in json output.

Maybe you can use boxed integers (Integer) for non required fields or use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"route"})` so that Jackson ignores it.

Comment: I tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"route"})` in the `SDBeanPost`  after this line `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` but I am getting this error `JsonIgnoreProperties cannot be resolved to a type`. I just want to delete the route and direction from the response if the route and direction have value in the request. Otherwise if the route has `0` and dierection has `""`  also empty in the request I want to return `{"status":230,"route":0. "direction": ""}`.

Comment: Just check whether you have imported JsonIgnoreProperties. Also if you want to send route when it's set, Use `Integer` instead of `int` in SDBeanPost for route